# No view found for id

Tags: android, android-fragment, kotlin, navigation-drawer

Tengo un Navigation drawer y quiero pasar de mi "ChallengeFragment" a mi "PerfilFragment" con un boton que puse

así que al pulsar el boton quiero que vaya al otro fragmento.

Este es el código que tengo en mi ChallengeFragment

```
val fragment  = PerfilFragment()
            val transaction: FragmentTransaction = childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_Perfil, fragment)
            transaction.addToBackStack(null)
            transaction.commit()
```

Este es el error que me ha dado

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.miproyecto, PID: 23000
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0a00a3 (com.example.miproyecto:id/fragment_Perfil) for fragment PerfilFragment{977a13} (03bd57e9-a82b-4d25-bab0-7859ae4080d7) id=0x7f0a00a3}
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:315)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1187)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1356)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1434)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1497)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:447)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2169)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1992)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1947)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1849)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:413)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Comment: Pero tengo entendido que no puedo usar intent para navegar de un Fragment a Otro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con respecto a el error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id

puedes tener 2 posibles causas.

A)

**Primeramente la causa más común es que al obtener la referencia de alguna de vista en tu layout mediante `findViewById()`, la vista no se encuentra**. Si la vista se encuentra inicialmente pero al realizar un reemplazo de fragment y por consiguiente de layout, debes asegurar que en este nuevo Fragmento (en este caso `PerfilFragment`) se encuentre la vista de la cual deseas obtener la referencia.

```
val fragment  = PerfilFragment()
            val transaction: FragmentTransaction = childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_Perfil, fragment)
            transaction.addToBackStack(null)
            transaction.commit()
```

B)

Si tu vista a la cual deseas obtener su referencia, en realidad se encuentre en el `Fragment` el cual reemplazaste, debes limpiar y construir nuevamente tu proyecto para que genere los ids de las vistas.